# How to skip some targets using commnd line (CMake)

Tags: cmake, xerces-c

I'm have dependency on Xerces-c++ and for `instal` target it always builds example executables and documentation. That consumes ~50% of build time (6 mins on my build VM).

My current build command is `cmake --build ${proj}\build_${platform} --config RelWithDebInfo --target install --parallel`.

How can I skip non essential targets?

It's third party dependency, so I don't want to modify `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: It seems Xerces-c++ doesn't allow you to skip building tests.  The best you can do is contribute a fix to the library. Following best practices, this would be wrapping the call to `add_subdirectory(tests)` in an `if(BUILD_TESTING)`.

Comment: @havogt May be there is another target available? How can i find out available targets? Btw, it's `samples`, not `tests`.

Comment: When using `Makefile` generator, you can call `make help` to list all available targets.

Comment: @arrowd I'm using Visual studio generator. There is no help target.

Comment: Then the target list can be observed in the solution explorer window - each project under your solution corresponds to a target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source there is no option to control the build of samples

```
add_subdirectory(samples)
```

ref: https://github.com/apache/xerces-c/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L172

But you can patch it !

```
option(BUILD_SAMPLES "Build samples" ON)
message(STATUS "Build samples: ${BUILD_SAMPLES}")
...
if(BUILD_SAMPLES)
  add_subdirectory(samples)
endif()
```

note: you can also enable CMP0077 if you have a super build...